# Tomcat Threads running forever

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a problem, my threads on tomcat is entering the Service phase but some of them never finish. What could be the cause of this problem? This application was running normally for some months but yesterday this started to happen.

[image: A IMAGE FROM TOMCAT MANAGER THREADS]

Here is one of the servlets that has this problem. But this can occur with any of them, I'm thinking it is occurring because of an infrastructure problem or tomcat or java configuration, but I'm not sure.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Connection conMysqlServidor = null;
    Connection conMysqlOperador = null;
    try {

        FornecedorDoPedido fornecedor = (FornecedorDoPedido) request.getSession().getAttribute("fornecedor");


        Operador operador = new OperadorDao().buscarDadosConexaoOperador(fornecedor.getCodOperadorDoPedido());

        conMysqlOperador = new ConnectionFactory().getConnectionMysqlOperador(operador, "database");
        conMysqlOperador.setAutoCommit(false);
        conMysqlServidor = new ConnectionFactory().getConnectionMysqlServidor();
        conMysqlServidor.setAutoCommit(false);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        JSONArray ofertasJson = new JSONArray(request.getParameter("json"));

        if(validaOfertas(ofertasJson, fornecedor.getCodPedido(), conMysqlOperador) && validaPedido(conMysqlOperador, fornecedor.getCodPedido())) {
            for(int i=0;i<ofertasJson.length();i++) {
                JSONObject ofertaJson = ofertasJson.getJSONObject(i);

                if(!ofertaJson.getString("oferta").replace(".", "").replace(",", ".").isEmpty() && !ofertaJson.getString("oferta").equals("0,00")) {
                    adicionarOferta(fornecedor, ofertaJson, conMysqlOperador);
                }

            }

            atualizaPodeOfertar(fornecedor, conMysqlServidor);


            conMysqlOperador.commit();
            conMysqlServidor.commit();

            response.getWriter().write(ControleJsonRetorno.criarEscopoJsonOk().toString());
        }else {
            JSONObject retorno = ControleJsonRetorno.criarEscopoJsonFalha();
            JSONObject falha = new JSONObject();
            falha.put("mensagem", "Ofertas inválidas!");
            retorno.getJSONObject("sucesso").getJSONArray("falhas").put(falha);
            response.getWriter().write(retorno.toString());
        }

    }catch(OfertaInvalidaException ofertaInvalidaException) {//TRATA OFERTA INVÁLIDA
        System.err.println(ofertaInvalidaException.getMessage());
        JSONObject retornoFalhoJson = ControleJsonRetorno.criarEscopoJsonFalha();
        JSONObject falhaJson = new JSONObject();
        falhaJson.put("mensagem", ofertaInvalidaException.getMessage());
        falhaJson.put("tipo", "ofertaInvalida");
        falhaJson.put("item", ofertaInvalidaException.getnInternoItem());
        //ADICIONADO 27/09/2016 TODO
        falhaJson.put("codigoBarra", ofertaInvalidaException.getCodigoBarra());
        falhaJson.put("descricao", ofertaInvalidaException.getDescricao());
        //
        falhaJson.put("oferta", ofertaInvalidaException.getValorOferta());
        retornoFalhoJson.getJSONObject("sucesso").getJSONArray("falhas").put(falhaJson);
        response.getWriter().write(retornoFalhoJson.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.getWriter().write(ControleJsonRetorno.criarEscopoJsonErro().toString());
    }finally {
        try {
            conMysqlOperador.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Erro no fechamento da conexão com banco de dados do cliente em " + this.getClass());
        }
        try {
            conMysqlServidor.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Erro no fechamento da conexão com banco de dados do servidor em " + this.getClass());
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: *"What could be the cause of this problem?"* Your code doesn't return.

Comment: What external services does your code call? Database? Did you check the database for deadlocks?

Comment: *but yesterday thi started to happen* - what changed yesterday?

Comment: I added a part of code from one of serlvets. Nothing was changed yesterday.

Comment: Take a thread dump to see what your code is doing.